Material to replace old 1" x 12" sheathing
I'm replacing siding and insulation on my house built in 1948.  Existing sheathing is rough cut 1"x12" pine boards horizontally over the studs. When removing the siding I found a spot that is rotten and needs to be replaced.  Should I find 5/4 x 12 boards to replace the bad ones or use 2 layers of 1/2" plywood so I match the same thickness, or is there a better option?
I'm dealing with the cause of the water damage, and may need to replace a stud or two.  The damaged section is part of two walls, and I'm not planning on removing/replacing all of the sheathing on these walls.
My new wall build has rockwool in the cavities, 1" foil faced foam, fibercement siding.
Damaged area is about 2' x 3' on one wall and 1' x 4' on the other.

It's an actual inch.  Same material was used for both interior and exterior sheathing throughout the house as well as for subfloor.

My uninformed opinion is to take out the rotten wood, leave the rest in place, put modern sheathing and weather seal over the whole thing. That's what we did with my "king's pine" boarded roof...

@keshlam, that's an option, but it doesn't resolve every scenario, like if the gaps are too large for the new sheathing to span them, and it can complicate the likes of window and door trim. It's also probably a needless expense.

Assuming that the original sheathing actually is 1" thick, which would be extraordinary, you wouldn't need to replicate that heavy-duty thickness. Just fur it out.
I'd use rips of the half-inch sheathing of your choice. OSB is just fine with me. I like to cut 1-3/4" or 2" rips so you don't have to be so precise when you tack them on the studs. Then install your sheathing over them.
To save material, cut all your sheathing patches first, then rip up the scrap that's left for furring strips. You can piece them in however it works out. It needn't be precise nor pretty.
